# Plotly: shareX between side-by-side plots

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I would like to have two side by side plots sharing the same X-axis and the same toolbar. This means that, by zooming in the first plot, the second plot should automatically resize to the same zoomed region.

A way to do that could be to stack the plots one above the other, using `shareX=TRUE`, but I need them to be side by side.

In python there seems to be a way to do that, using `fig.update_xaxes(matches='x')`. Is there a similar option in R?

Here is a sample code:

```
library(plotly) 

n = 10
x = 1:n
y = rnorm(n)

fig1 <- plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers') 
fig2 <- plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers') 
fig  <- subplot(fig1, fig2, shareX = TRUE) # shareX actually not working here
fig
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `matches` in R just as we can in python.

Run `schema()` and navigate:

object ► layout ► layoutAttributes ► xaxis ► matches

for more info.

This keeps all (x&y) axes synced:

```
library(plotly) 

n = 10
x = 1:n
y = rnorm(n)

fig1 <- plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers') 
fig2 <- plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers', xaxis = "x") %>% layout(xaxis = list(matches = "x"))
fig  <- subplot(fig1, fig2, shareX = TRUE, shareY = TRUE)
fig
```

[image: result]

Comment: For future readers: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70953812/9841389) you can find a related post.